# Are Release Environment Artifact Filters available for onsite TFS 2017?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

According to the Microsoft documentation we should be able to enable Artifact Filters for Release Environments with onsite TFS 2017 update 3, but this feature seems to be missing from our onsite server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/release/triggers#env-triggers

Do we need to upgrade to TFS 2018 to have this feature?

The following question discusses the usage of this feature, but not its availability:
[VSTS Release Management: filter by branch on artifact source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36596542/vsts-release-management-filter-by-branch-on-artifact-source)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation isn't clear on this point, and the developercommunity post is incorrect:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/175267/release-environment-artifact-triggers-not-availabl.html

The comment below from @MarinaLiu-MSF confirms Environment Artifact Filters feature are not available for onsite TFS 2017 nor for the first release of onsite TFS 2018. **To date, this functionality is only currently available in the online VSTS.**

I found a post on the VisualStudio User Voice site that mentions it being available in the next major on-prem version:  https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13413054-trigger-release-definition-only-for-specific-branc

> ADMIN
>   VSTS Team (Product group, Microsoft Visual Studio) responded  ·  July 11, 2017
>   We are happy to let you know that your suggestion is now available on Team Services. 
>   It will become available to the on-prem version in the next major version of TFS.
>   You can read more about it at https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/triggers#release-triggers

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT In fact my answer is incomplete. I have installed TFS 2018, I get the new Pipeline view for defining my releases, but I still don't see the Artifact Filters in the environment pre-deployment triggers. Do I need to enable this feature somewhere?

Comment: Seems you already report the issue in developer community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/175267/release-environment-artifact-triggers-not-availabl.html, you can get the feedback later. And Yes, artifact filters is not available for TFS2017 and TFS2018 (but for VSTS) now.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT  your answer on https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/175267/release-environment-artifact-triggers-not-availabl.html does not correspond with your answer here. Which answer is correct?

Comment: I didn't answer in developer community forum. For now, artifact filters is not available for TFS2018, and it's investigating by our feature team. You can wait for the response.